# How can get Value from child component in react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, components, submit

I create a `InputComponent` and I want to import this component in other component and do submit, but I can't do it. how can I get value from child component in my FormComponent

**InputComponent.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class InputComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { currentVal: null }
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <input  
                    value={this.state.currentVal}
                    onChange={(event) => this.setState({currentVal:event.target.value })}
                   /> 
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default InputComponent;
```

**FormComponent.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import InputComponent from '../../components/common/InputComponent';

class FormComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }


    CallSubmit= (event) => {  
        // how can get username and password ?

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.vale)

    }

    render() { 
        return ( 

            <div style={{width:100, height:500, marginTop:100}}>
                <form onSubmit={  this.CallSubmit }>
                    <InputComponent name="username" />
                    <InputComponent name="password" />

                    <button>Send it</button>
                </form>
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default FormComponent;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an onChange action on child component, for example here is your FormComponent: 
Create this function to handle change:

```
onChangeUsername(username){
 this.setState({username})
 }
```

Passing the props to child component:

```
<InputComponent name="username" onChange = {this.onChangeUsername} />
```

And in the child component(InputComponent), you can access this props and pass the data to it:

```
this.props.onChange(event.target.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

move your onChange functions in parent component and store username and password in `FormComponent` component

Comment: i don't understand, can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

In React, data flows **one way**, from parent to children.

Therefore, you need to have the input' actual states at the `FormComponent` and pass them as props to the `InputComponent`, and the function that deals with it at the `FormComponent` either.

```
<div>
  <InputComponent 
    input={this.state.username} 
    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  />
  <InputComponent 
    input={this.state.password} 
    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  />
</div>
```

A good article to understand it: https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4286486-build-web-apps-with-reactjs/4286721-understand-one-way-data-bindings